# Strange function in IDA Pro: Only one basic block ending with a jmp sub_xxxxxx (instead of a ret)

Tags: ida, disassembly, idapython, compilers, functions

[image: IDA Pro function with no ret as last instruction but a jump to a label]

Analyzing the ELF file /usr/bin/curl (Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit), I stumbled upon a strange function (see image). It is called regularly via `call sub_403D90` but does not end with a ret. Instead, it jumps to a label / another function (`sub_403C90`).
This is strange because there seems to be no return to `sub_403D90`, as from `sub_403C90` onwards in the control flow, there are no jumps but only rets.

Can someone explain to me why this is? Does it makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a bit of optimization. A `call xxxx` followed by a `ret` can be optimized to a `jmp xxxx`.

Comment: Commonly known as "Tail Call" elimination / optimization.

Comment: @IanCook: Thank you for the keyword. I only came up with "tail recursion elimination", which isn't the case here, so i decided to omit it.